# Increase Text Size Without Increasing Block Size in Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I notice that the more my text increases in each block the more the size of the block itself as can be seen in the `block` label with n-1 related to other blocks.

**What I want**

1. I want bocks of the same sizes regardless of the text lengths.
2. I want the inscribed texts in each of my blocks to occupy up to 80% of each `block` size without the block sizes increasing.
3. I want bigger `2, 3, 4, ..., n-1` while I want the block size to be the same as the first three blocks.

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
       block/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           inner sep=1em
       }
       ]
    
       \path node[block,black,fill=yellow] (1st) {2\strut};
       \path (1st.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,black,fill=green] 
       (2nd) {3\strut};
       \path (2nd.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,black,fill=red] 
       (3rd) {4\strut};
       \path (3rd.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,black,fill=white] 
       (4th) {...\strut};
       \path (4th.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,black,fill=yellow] 
       (5th) {n-1\strut};
    
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}

[image: coloured blocks]

Comment: Use `inner sep=0pt` and both `mimial width=<value>` and `mimial height=<value>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment above:

Without `font=\huge`:

[image: Increase without]

With `font=\huge`:

[image: Increase text size]

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/631402/204164
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
       block/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           inner sep=0pt,
           minimum width=1cm,
           minimum height=1cm ,
           font=\huge         
       }
       ]
    
       \path node[block,black,fill=yellow] (1st) {2\strut};
       \path (1st.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,black,fill=green] 
       (2nd) {3\strut};
       \path (2nd.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,black,fill=red] 
       (3rd) {4\strut};
       \path (3rd.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,black,fill=white] 
       (4th) {...\strut};
       \path (4th.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,black,fill=yellow] 
       (5th) {n-1\strut};
    
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```